# NIntegrate a very sharp function

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have a very sharp function `s[t]` which is I want to numerically integrate, here it is:

```
u[j_, k_, k1_, 
  a_] := (SphericalBesselJ[j + 1/2, k a] SphericalBesselJ[j - 1/2, 
      k1 a] - SphericalBesselJ[j - 1/2, k a] SphericalBesselJ[j + 1/2,
       k1 a])/(SphericalHankelH1[j + 1/2, k a] SphericalBesselJ[
      j - 1/2, k1 a] - 
    SphericalHankelH1[j - 1/2, k a] SphericalBesselJ[j + 1/2, k1 a])
lmax = 60;
s[t_, k_, k1_, a_] := 
 2/(1 + Cos[t]) Norm[
    Sum[(l + 1) (LegendreP[l + 1, Cos[t]] + LegendreP[l, Cos[t]]) u[
       l + 1/2, k, k1, a], {l, 0, lmax}]]^2
k = 0.5; q = 1; a = 100; k1 = k - q;
Plot[s[t, k, k1, a], {t, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The integral I want to do is:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[t] s[t, k, k1, a], {t, 0, Pi}]/
 NIntegrate[Sin[t] (1 - Cos[t]) s[t, k, k1, a], {t, 0, Pi}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

I've received a lot of errors when doing this integral and I am not sure if the `result` is correctly or not.

#### Edit:

The possible result is `2.4951`, I derived it semi-analytically, but I am not sure if it is right or not.

Comment: Up to the plot, 2.4951 is not correct.

Comment: @user64494 you mean the value should be larger?

Comment: I mean the unclaimed edit in your question. There was no fraction in the original question and the integrand in the numerator was changed too. Compare with the Sumit's answer https://www.dropbox.com/s/0agjojzr5etq10z/screen18.02.17.docx?dl=0.

Comment: It seems you have caused great confusion because the the function in the plot shown here is not the integrand.

Comment: Also the `Sin[t]` factor in the integrand cancels the peak in `s[]` and makes it irrelevant to the integral.  The oscillatory nature of `s[]` is more significant.

Comment: @user64494 review the edit history, I have the fraction all the time.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement @buzhidao's answer, there is a way to predict the needed `WorkingPrecision` for a given `PrecisionGoal`.  (`AccuracyGoal` doesn't matter much in this example, since the integrals are so large.)

First a measure of the conditioning:

```
k = 1/2; k1 = k - q; (* to make code exact, for high precision *)
logcond =  With[{wp = 100}, 
  wp - Precision[Sin[t] s[t, k, k1, a] /. t -> N[Subdivide[0, Pi, 16][[2 ;; -2]], wp]]
  ]

(*  Out[106]= 22.2319  *)
```

There's a loss of 22+ digits.  The working precision (WP) needs to be at least this large, plus whatever is needed to achieve a given precision goal (PG).  The heuristic *Mathematica* uses is WP = 2 * PG.  In poorly conditioned problems, WP may need to have a higher ratio.  In this case 2*PG is enough, but `NIntegrate` runs a bit faster with 4*PG or higher, up to some point. (This suggests that the ill-conditioning is showing up in the error estimate.)

```
Block[{wp, pg},
 pg = 8; (* precision goal *)
 wp = logcond + 4 pg; (* +2pg  is normal, seems to work; +4pg is faster *)
 NIntegrate[Sin[t] s[t, k, k1, a], {t, 0, Pi},
     WorkingPrecision -> wp, PrecisionGoal -> pg]/
   NIntegrate[Sin[t] (1 - Cos[t]) s[t, k, k1, a], {t, 0, Pi},
    WorkingPrecision -> wp, PrecisionGoal -> pg] // AbsoluteTiming
 ]
(*  Out[114]= {7.50135, 2.49510186134610385390934586152274152298365069672002498}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the combination of `WorkingPrecision` and `AccuracyGoal`, I am able to eliminate the warnings and get the *supposed* value, i.e. `2.4951`. Here is 
the code:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[t] s[t, k, k1, a], {t, 0, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 6]/
 NIntegrate[Sin[t] (1 - Cos[t]) s[t, k, k1, a], {t, 0, Pi}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 6]
```

> 2.49510186134610350267992744002

Comment: Both the numerator (= 2755.39038618878269174009269118) and the denominator (= 1104.31979907315439966452460777) contradict the plot in the question.

Comment: @user64494 I don't see why, please elaborate it, maybe write an answer about it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can try different [NIntegrate Integration Strategies](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html). For diverging functions, try to use different Singularity Handling techniques.

(I am going with `lmax=30` to save time)

You must be careful about what is causing the sharpness. If it is a divergence then you can specify that in your `NIntegrate`. For example, if I mention that `0` is a singularity

```
NIntegrate[s[t, k, k1, a], {t, -Pi, Pi, 0}]
```

> 13145.6

and without that

```
NIntegrate[s[t, k, k1, a], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

> 26291.1

If you are sure that your function does not have any divergence (which I think is true in this case) try to increase `MaxRecursion` to see if the result changes.

```
NIntegrate[s[t, k, k1, a], {t, -Pi, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

> 26291.1

```
NIntegrate[s[t, k, k1, a], {t, -Pi, Pi}, MaxRecursion -> 50]
```

> 26291.1

Comment: @ Sumit : Your answer 26291.1 is not in accordance with the plot for lmax= 30. Also s[0, k, k1, a] equals 225195. in this case. Therefore, there is no singularity at $t=0$.

Comment: @user64494, I agree there is no singularity ("If you are sure that your function does not have any divergence (which I think is true in this case)..."). I give here a general prescription so I mentioned both possibilities. About lmax=30, I have to check the calculation again :)